# Can a polytope cone always be embedded in 2D?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, polytopes

Assume you have $k$ half spaces which all intersect at the same vertex forming a cone.

In 2D this forms just a point as no other point exist inside the cone.

In 3D this forms a pyramid with a polygonal face, which can be trivially embedded in 2D.

Is it true for the higher dimension ones that the cone is embeddable in 2D?

Comment: I'm not sure I agree with the geometry you describe. In 2D you can intersect arbitrarily many half-spaces that, say, all have $0$ on their boundaries, and still obtain an angle, not just a point.

Comment: Similarly, in 3D you can intersect as many half-spaces as you want while still obtaining a convex cone with non-empty interior. Such a polytope cannot be embedded in $\Bbb R^2$.